# Cant delete avd in Android studio

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I'm running Android Studio 1.1 (Latest update installed). When i try to delete a AVD in this version, an error displays "AVD already running in emulator. close the emulator and try again". But , I cant find any AVDs running in my system. how can i solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search for *.lock folders under C:\Users\username\.android folder and delete those. This should tell Android studio that the AVD is not running.

Comment: works. but every time i open a avd, the same error occurs. I have to delete and re create the avds

Answer (score 0):

You need to force close the AVD and then delete again.

If you are unable to force close. Then restart your computer. Open Android Studio. and then delete agaoin. This will work.

Comment: i restared, re installed, tried everything. same error

Comment: Don't need to reinstall. Most of the cases after restarting your computer Android studio enables us to delete avd.